# parameter type "int" incompatible parameter type "HWND" while trying to create an instance of check box

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I added a check box with ID "IDC_BLACK" in a dialog box. As I tried to get the reference of the check box it says,  type "int" is incompatible with type "HWND".

```
CButton *m_ctlCheck = new CButton;

m_ctlCheck = reinterpret_cast<CButton *>(GetDlgItem(IDC_BLACK));
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Apparently, this code is not within a member function of a class derived from `CWnd`, and so `GetDlgItem` refers to `::GetDlgItem` (a Windows API function that takes an `HWND` and a control ID) rather than `CWnd::GetDlgItem` (an MFC wrapper for the former, which only takes the control ID since `HWND` is available from `CWnd` instance). If you want to call the member function, you need an object to call it on.

Comment: If the code you show worked, it would lead to a memory leak. First you make `m_ctrCheck` point to a dynamically allocated `CButton` object, then you want to reassign the pointer and make it point somewhere else, losing the original pointer. C++ isn't Java, you don't have to use `new` to create a reference (or pointer in this case) to an object.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik This code is on MFC, I tried                                      CButton *m_ctlCheck = (CButton *)CWnd::GetDlgItem(IDC_BLACK)); It says "a non-static member reference must be relative to specific object".

Comment: Which part of "you need an **object**" do you find unclear? Somewhere in your program, there should be a variable that represents a dialog currently shown on the screen. It is this variable that you should call `GetDlgItem` on.