# MFC "memory allocation violation"

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I created a check box in a dialog box and trying to access its condition whether checked or not. This is my code:

```
CButton *m_ctlCheckBlack = (CButton *)GetDlgItem(IDC_BLACK);

int chkBoxBlack = m_ctlCheckBlack->GetCheck();
```

As I run through this code, it pops up an exception saying :

```
Exception thrown at 0x0FA45564 (mfc140d.dll) in braille_obr.exe: 0xC0000005:      
Access violation reading location 0x00000020.
```

any help will be appreciated. thank you.

Comment: You already asked about this earlier http://stackoverflow.com/q/36180788/4603670 --- It's hard to say by just looking at 2 lines of code. People can guess what the problem is or you can take the time to explain what you are doing.

Comment: I suppose `m_ctlCheckBlack` is `NULL` for some reason.

Comment: From where are you calling the function that contains the 2 lines of code you posted?

Answer (score 1):

There is rarely a good reason to use GetDlgItem. In your resource editor, right click the button and 'Add Variable..'
It will default as a control. Give it a name. You will get a member in the dialog class:

```
CButton myButtonName;
```

Now it should be safe to:

```
myButtonName.GetChecked( );
```

as it will have been created and properly subclassed.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, I doubt it tried to get the state of button when the Button was not yet constructed.

```
int chkBoxBlack = m_ctlCheckBlack != NULL ? m_ctlCheckBlack->GetCheck() : 0;
```

Or, do you try to operate from outside dialog?
If it is so, you had better try to do this.

```
■CButton *m_ctlCheckBlack = (CButton *)yourdlg.GetDlgItem(IDC_BLACK);

■FindWindowEx(yourdlg.GetSafeHwnd(), NULL, NULL, "(your button caption)");
```

Comment: it returns a 0, but I did construct the button. What might be the possible issue?

Comment: What event handler is this code written in?
Even if CButton instance has already been created, Button Control as a part of GUI does not yet exist, does it?

Comment: I created a check box with ID " IDC_BLACK". The CButton is referencing to that check box. I did create a check box in the GUI. @nariuji

Comment: If you write this code in OnCreate() or OnUpdate(), it is possible those events run earlier than the action of Button Control's create.
I think there are some events like that.

Comment: Have you tried using GetSafeHwnd() and only if not null run the GetCheck method.